# What would be the time and space complexity of this recursive combination problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have made a variation of the code I wrote for [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/combinations/):

> Given two integers n and k, return all possible combinations of k numbers chosen from the range [1, n]. You may return the answer in any order.

I was able to pass the test cases, but I was trying something else:

```
function solution(a, k) {
    let result = [];
    result = count(start = 0, result, a, curr = [], 2, 0);
    return result.length
}

function count(start, result, a, curr, currLen) {
    if (curr.length === currLen) {
        if (result.includes(curr)) return;
        if (curr[0] < curr[1]) result.push([...curr]);
        return;
    }

    for (let i = start; i < a.length; i++) {
        curr.push(i);
        count(i + 1, result, a, curr, currLen, times += 1);
        curr.pop();
    }

    return result;
}

const a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Would the time complexity be O(a.length)?

Is the space complexity simply O(2 * result.length) = O(result.length)?

If you could please give an explanation of how to approach this problem, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code will throw an error if `result.includes(curr)` or `curr[0] < curr[1]`

Comment: What complexity is of interest for you: best, average or worst case? BTW: What is the parameter `times` for? It's never used.

Comment: @ Konrad - I tried it out and it doesn't seem to throw an error for me. @Mushroomator - worst case. times is a typo - i was using it for something else. editing it out rn

Comment: The function `count` has 5 parameters, yet you call it with 6 arguments.

Comment: `result.includes(curr)` is always going to be false. Maybe you should focus your question on what this algorithm is supposed to do, because it looks like it isn't correct.

Comment: hi i re-edited my code to provide the link to the leetcode question and my code for that particular question that was accepted (which is what my original code was based on and is a variation of) to give more context and make it clearer that whatever i wrote does work for javascript.

Comment: Well, I had posted all these issues in my answer, and now you updated your question with it making my answer look irrelevant. Can you please not do that anymore? I will now update my answer and align it again with your question, but it would be nice if you would not change things to your question that are addressed in answers.

Comment: Also, don't include results from the answers back into your question. If you doubt an answer, then ask via comments, but don't do that in your updated question. If you feel there still remains a follow up question, then you can consider asking a new question.

Comment: I rolled back those changes in your question. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are a few things that are never used, or not needed:

- `k` is never used.
- `times` is an undefined variable
- `count` is called with a 6<sup>th</sup> argument that is not going anywhere.
- The values in array `a` are never used, only its length, so we could just omit `a` and only work with the length value
- `result.includes(curr)` always returns false, but does represent work, so it cannot be discarded for determining time complexity.
- `curr[0] < curr[1]` is always true (because the recursive call is made with `i + 1` for `start`)

#### Time complexity

We may assume that `push` and `pop` have amortised O(1) time complexity. Also `[...curr]` has O(1) time complexity because the length of `curr` is `curLen`, which is constant (2).

The time to perform the recursive call is also constant per time that `curr` is pushed to the result, as the recursion depth is `curLen`.

If we ignore the `includes` call, the time complexity is driven by the number of times the base case is executed, i.e. how many subarrays are pushed to the `result` array. This number is the number of ways to choose `curLen` items of `a.length` items. In other words, with `curLen` equal to 2, it is (─1)/2 where  is `a.length`. This means the time complexity is O(²).

However, the useless `includes` call makes the time complexity worse. Each time the whole result array is iterated, and so we get a time complexity of O(<sup>4</sup>).

#### Space complexity

The space used by `result` is the only space that is not constant in nature. The call stack usage is constant because the recursion depth is limited to a constant (`curLen`). The `curr` arrays are also constant in length.

So the space complexity is O(²).

### When `k` is an input

It turns out that `curLen` is supposed to be the `k` that is passed as second argument. When that is an *input*, then the complexity not only depends on , but also on .

In that case the recursion depth is  and the length of the subarrays is , and the number of subarrays in the final result is [-choose-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). So the number of individual values of `i` that are stored in all subarrays together is  (,) and each represents constant time to get it there.

If we ignore the `includes` expression, this makes both the time and space complexity O( (,)). With the `includes` operation, the time complexity degrades to O( (,)²)

Comment: someone else answered that the time complexity is O(2^n). I am not sure who is correct?

Comment: hi i re-edited my code to provide the link to the leetcode question and my code for that particular question that was accepted (which is what my original code was based on and is a variation of) to give more context and make it clearer that whatever i wrote does work for javascript.

Comment: That's not nice. Now my answer looks unrelated to your question. I rolled back the changes you made to the question.

Comment: Someone answered with a different time complexity. I gave the reasoning as to why your algorithm has the time complexity I mentioned. If you have a specific point of reasoning from my answer that you doubt, then please let me know. Of course, I stand by my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't.

Even assuming that the 1st part of `count` code is O(1) (which depends on implementation of `push`, but it probably is O(curr.length), the second part, the recursive one, cost is apparently O(2**a.length).

To evaluate the complexity of a recursive function, you often end up defining a recursive series mimicking the recursion of the function itself. Here

```
Cost(n) = Cost of count(start=a.length-n)
Cost(n) = 1 + Cost(n-1)+Cost(n-2)+...+Cost(1)+Cost(0)
```

Which means that Cost(n) is O(2**n).

(built it from the bottom: Cost(0)=1 ; Cost(1)=1+1 ; Cost(2) = Cost(1)+Cost(0)+1=2+1+1=4 ; Cost(3)=Cost(2)+Cost(1)+Cost(0)+1 = 4+2+1+1=8 ; ...)

Comment: Are you saying that the time complexity is O(2^n)? bc someone else answered that the time complexity should be O(n^4). I am confused on how you guys got such different answers and what the actual correct answer is

Comment: hi i re-edited my code to provide the link to the leetcode question and my code for that particular question that was accepted (which is what my original code was based on and is a variation of) to give more context and make it clearer that whatever i wrote does work for javascript.

Comment: Well, that other person is trincot, who is usually right. My answer assumed that "2" was an arbitrary parameter, so I count worse case scenario, and count only recursion, ignoring what happens before. And what happens before is O(1) (we agree on that hypothesis, and probably agree that it is not exactly true, but a reasonnable hypothesis). But can "cut" the recursion.

Comment: Your new version of the code replaced that "2" by "k". Which seem to validate my hypothesis. But in another hand, context makes clear that k<n. And answer is your code is O(2ⁿ) while n<=k. Just count the number of recursion (and as far as complexity is concerned, any count, O-wise, is a lower boundary of global time complexity). It is not just O(2ⁿ), it is litteraly O(2ⁿ): 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64,...

Comment: Until n reaches k+1. After which, it starts to behave more and more as O(n⁴).

Comment: So, not to say "we were both right". Trincot's answer is more on the spot, now that we have context, and it is clear that it is meant to have a relatively small, fixed, k, with a growing n. Since big-O are to be undertood "when n→∞", well, when n→∞, k becomes negligible before n, and therefore it is indeed O(n⁴), and the O(2ᵏ) you find in it is just a constant from n point of view.

Comment: I repeat here what I said elsewhere: don't edit your question like that when there are answers posted. This is pulling the rug under those answers. I rolled back the changes to your question that would invalidate the answers.